# How to remove/stop every kind of reboot task from Windows?

Tags: windows-10, reboot

My computer automatically restarts itself at random times, it may happen 1 to 3 times each time I use it, sometimes it restarts itself even at a very early moment when I want just turned it on and then I'm going o type my username-password, sometimes it does it after 2 hours. No clue when and why. I disabled the auto update and auto restart after update. So problem is not from there. It is not related to the electricity as well. The IT section also ran a test on memory etc and they told me that there is no problem with memory etc. They didn't find the reason for the restarts. Therefore if it is not related to the hardware, it should be some reboot task somewhere in my windows which is causig the problem. All my software and stuff that I installed and use are also on my personal laptop and I also used them on my former office PCs. Therefore there is no problem with softwares and files that are installed and used on it by me.

The last hope I have is to find a way to force windows to never ever reboot itself. I also never restart my computer, if it needs a reboot, then I prefer to turn it off and then turn it on and at least so far I never installed something that needs restarting computer to complete installation. So I think this will be a good solution for me to just prevent any reboot task. But when I search about it at internet, all related posts are about stopping reboot task of auto-update which is not what I want. I want stopping all of reboot tasks of any type. I will be happy if someone has any idea about how I should do this.

I'm using windows 10, 64bit.

---

A screenshot of the eventviewer, administrative events, asked in the comments.
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the event viewer? It should list the reboot/shutdown reason.

Comment: If it happens while you run the BIOS setup for hours, then it's a hardware issue (maybe mainboard / power supply). Please put basic info in your question: how many years is the machine old and how many hours was the RAM tested?

Comment: @MMM what should I exactly look for in event viewer and where of it, I'm not familiar with event viewer.

Comment: @Furty what do you exactly mean by running the BIOS setup for hours? I just turn on computer and use it for my work, coding, computation, writing, email etc. The person who checked my computer said he ran test for 24 hours. I don't have details of his tests and results. He only said he didn't find a problem with memory or other thing. And I don't think it is a problem of electricity, because it doesn't get off, it restarts and I changed the electricity plug and also tested connecting other electrical things to the electricity plugs of my office.

Comment: BIOS: the key to press will be displayed when you start your computer (or look for it in the mainboard manual). But if the RAM test was really running for 24h, then maybe it's a software issue. In [Event Viewer](https://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-10/how-to-use-event-viewer-in-windows-10/) check especially the "Administrative Events" before and after reboot. What do they say?

Comment: Dying disks can also cause strange problems. Please post a screenshot of [CrystalDiskInfo](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-test-your-pc-for-failing-hardware/).

Comment: @Furty I added screenshot from the eventviewer.

Comment: Could be a hardware problem, so please also add  
a) the already requested CrystalDiskInfo screenshot
b) screenshot of [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to see if there was a bluescreen and if a driver is marked red

Comment: @Furty sorry for late respond. The problem got solved. The university suggested the following which solved the issue, now I don't encounter those sudden restarts: "When starting the computer press <Del> key to enter BIOS setup. Then choose Overclocking/Advanced CPU Configuration and disable Core Performance Boost."

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Even if that sounds strange, you should add this as answer (including mainboard model), so other people with the same issue can upvote it to improve your reputation on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Furty for his comments, I learnt about new things such as the event viewer etc.

The university gave the following solution which after applying it, the random restarts didn't happen again.

> When starting the computer press  key to enter BIOS setup. Then choose Overclocking/Advanced CPU Configuration and disable Core Performance Boost.

The information about mainboard of the computer (System Model in the System Inofrmation):

> MS-7B38